# Full tar backup on Linux, excluding certain root folders

Tags: linux, tar, archlinux

I've got a question that I can't seem to find the answer to.

I'm trying to write a shell script to do a full system backup using tar. Obviously, there are several folders I do no want to backup (/dev, /mnt, /proc, /tmp, and so on). There are a fair number of folders I do no want backed up so I'm using the 'exclude-from' flag to keep the command relatively clean.

The problem is, it's not working.

Here are the tar flags I'm using:

```
--create
--file $BACKUP_FILE
--preserve-permissions
--same-owner
--numeric-owner
--listed-incremental $INCREMENTAL_FILE
--level=0
--xz
--directory /
--exclude-caches
--exclude-from $EXCLUDE_FILE
-v
```

Here is my exclude file:

```
/dev
/lost+found
/media
/mnt
/proc
/run
/sys
/tmp
/var/spool
/var/run
/var/tmp
```

When I run my script it still backups up those folders I don't want backed up. Switching to a bunch of '--exclude' flags doesn't seem to work (and I would rather not use them). I've tried changing '--exclude-from $EXCLUDE_FILE' to '--exclude-from=$EXCLUDE-FILE', I've made sure there's no whitespace after each line and a few other things (can't remember them, things are starting to blur together).

I've been reading up on tar patterns so see if there is something I'm missing and I haven't come across anything yet. I'm tried looking to see if this has something to do with tar stripping leading slashes for security purposes but I haven't found anything yet.

While Googling the only thing I found that sort of helps was one guy that was doing the same thing and solved it by removing the leading '/' from his exclude file entries. I've tried it and it works, but it excludes ALL folders rather than the root ones. I will likely have a 'media' folder in my home and I want to back that one up but not the /media folder so this isn't a proper solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So go figure, I found a possible solution 30 minutes after posting. If I change my exclude file entries to start with './' (rather than '/') it seems to work. This makes sense because I'm changing the directory to root so ./media === /media.

However, I'm not going to mark this as the answer just yet. I would very much like to keep my exclude file entries as '/' rather than './' so that it's obvious that I'm excluding the the root folders. Yes, I can leave a comment in the exclude file saying the current directory is the root directory, but if I can I would prefer to avoid it.

Comment: Since you're using Arch, have you looked at [the ArchWiki post on this subject](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backup)? You'll probably be interested in the section on rsync, since it does most of this and also supports incremental backups (only what's changed). I could be wrong but I believe tar would create a whole new tarball each time.

Comment: Yes I have. I choose tar for a variety of reasons (and it can do incremental/differential backups). I have also read https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Full_System_Backup_with_tar, which is doing what I'm trying (exclude file with absolute paths). However, the only differences I see between it and what I'm doing is that they have an '=' after the flag, a trailing '/' for an excluded directory (which from what I understand I DON'T want because it will copy the folder and not the contents and I don't want to copy the folder period) and a different flag order, all of which I tried.

Comment: OK. I don't know enough about tar to help you. If you have not already, you might consider posting on the Arch forums or self posting at reddit.com/r/archlinus

Answer (score 5):

Although the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/) includes instructions on how to perform a [full system backup with tar](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Full_System_Backup_with_tar), you probably want to use [rsync](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rsync) instead. The [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/) also describes how to perform a [full system backup with rsync](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/full_system_backup_with_rsync). As root, run:

```
rsync -aAXv --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} /* /path/to/backup/folder
```

The `-aAX` set of options will ensure that 'archive mode' is used. This ensures that symbolic links, devices, permissions and ownerships, modification times, ACLs and extended attributes are preserved.

Note that rsync can also read exclude patterns from file, so your use case may look something like:

```
rsync -aAXv --exclude-from=FILE /* /path/to/backup/folder
```

If you plan on backing up your system somewhere other than `/mnt` or `/media`, do not forget to add it to the list of exclude patterns to avoid an infinite loop. Also, if there are any bind mounts in the system, they should be excluded as well, so that the bind mounted contents are copied only once.

Comment: I appreciate being informed of alternatives, however I did read up on on using rsync and instead choose to go with tar.

Comment: @anEverydayGuy: May I ask why?

Comment: Ultimately it boils down to what they were designed for (and therefore are best at, despite both being able to do the job). Tar is designed for backing up / long term storage where rsync is designed for mirroring / transferring files. It's easy for tar to do a full / differential / incremental backup; it's more involved to get rsync to do a differential backup. Plus I got tar working first (tried both at the same time) and I have more experience with tar.

Comment: @anEverydayGuy: Tar was initially developed to run tape backups and that's where the name comes from - (T)ape (ar)chive. Today, tar is really just an archive utility. Yes, you can use it to run your backups because it includes those options, but rsync is a newer, much more versatile tool that is better equipped to perform data backups because it performs mirroring by default and has remote file transfer built in. However, I've never needed to create a differential (or 'true' incremental) backup before, so I really can't comment. Maybe this will help: https://rsync.samba.org/examples.html

Comment: If you want to use `rsync` over a network connection i.e. to back up to a remote server then it can be useful to add the `-z` flag to enable data compression. YMMV of course.